# Move all .htacces configurations in cakephp to Apache virtual host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

My intention is to speed up the performance of the cake app. I copied all the .htaccess files from my cake app, and despite the configtest saying all is ok, I still get an internal server error when I try and load the page. Is this the correct way to bring in .htaccess files from the app directory?

```
<Directory /var/www/html/aga-stag>
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all


    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kwiksta\.com [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.kwiksta.com/$1 [L,R=301]

        RewriteRule ^(red5|oflaDemo) - [L]

        RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

        RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteBase /app/
       RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
       RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
 </Directory>
```

Comment: It would perhaps be helpful if you actually included the error in your question. What does it say in the Apache logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess files are valid apache conf syntax, so in principle all you need to do is copy and paste the htaccess file's contents into the right place. However *don't* blindly do that.

This is more appropriate for handling your kwiksta.com -> www.kwiksta.com redirects:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName kwiksta.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.kwiksta.com{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

This snippet:

```
RewriteRule ^(red5|oflaDemo) - [L]
```

Is better handled by just putting (or symlinking) those folders (assuming that's what they are) into the webroot

And this is all that's required to then handle your CakePHP application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aga-stag/app/webroot
    ServerName www.kwiksta.com
    AllowOverride None # No need for htaccess files now

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the document root points at the webroot folder as it should for a [any and all production installs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation.html#production), which renders 2 of the 3 htaccess files irrelevant.

Be sure that the rewrite rules match the version of CakePHP you are using as they [changed](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.0/app/webroot/.htaccess#L5) [over](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/app/webroot/.htaccess) [time](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/webroot/.htaccess#L4).